# Wrapping words at the right point

Tags: html, css

I would like to wrap the text inside a div container, but I don't want words to be cut at some "random" character.

I have tried with `style="word-wrap: normal"`, but that only works in IE, not in Firefox. When using `style="white-space: some option"`, words get cut at unwanted points. For example the word "reason" is shown as "reas" at the end of the line and "on" at the beginning of the next line. Using the option "nowrap" is not ok, because the text exceeds the margins of the div container.

```
<div style="text-align: justify;">I agree, fully and voluntarily, to participate in this research study. With this, I retain the right to withdraw my consent, without having to give a reason for doing so.</div>
```

I would like that word wrapping occurs at the end of each line, if the space is insufficient for the whole text inside the div container. But I also want words to be sliced in a grammatically correct way or not sliced at all: simply show the word that does not fit at the end of the line in the following line.

This is the situation right now:

[image: So is the text shown in Firefox right now]

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking about? It sounds like you're asking for the wrapping behavior that's already standard - perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: I would like that the wrapping behavior posted above actually happens when using Firefox or some other non-IE browser. Thank you

Comment: You must have some other CSS causing that to happen. That is not default behavior in any browser. If you create a blank HTML page and dump that snippet into the body, it will wrap with exactly the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: There may be some other CSS causing that problem. But I can't see or edit it, because my code is inside a given box given by Unipark platform. Is there anything I can do to overwrite the other CSS options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your CSS is set to use `word-break: break-all`. If you change / override it to use `word-break: normal` then it won't happen anymore.

Demo:

```css
div { width: 190px; background: #ffc; }

#div1 { word-break: break-all; }
#div2 { word-break: normal; }
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  Without having to give a reason.
  Without having to give a reason.
  Without having to give a reason.
</div>
<br>
<div id="div2">
  Without having to give a reason.
  Without having to give a reason.
  Without having to give a reason.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank actually worked! I have been trying with word-wrap, but not with word-break. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if you tried this, but the answer may be to simply increase the size of the border

```
border-width = //put a value here
```

Comment: That might work. But then I would have to find out which width to use in each div container I have. Do you know any other option to do this easily?. Thank you

Comment: Actually that wouldn't work, because the page is responsive and the margins would have to be variable depending on the size of the window where the text is shown.